# Creating Composite Key Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5, composite-key

Shortly, I want to create composite keys on my table remaining with the primary key in order to improve sql server search performance. The performance issue occurs on 200k data table whenever I search an entity without primary key (i.e a string of GUID).  Assume that I have 3 classes

```
public class Device{

    public int ID { get; set; } 
    public string UDID { get; set; }
    public string ApplicationKey { get; set; }
    public string PlatformKey { get; set; }

    public ICollection<NotificationMessageDevice> DeviceMessages { get; set; } 
}

public class NotificationMessageDevice { 

    [Column(Order = 0), Key, ForeignKey("NotificationMessage")]
    public int NotificationMessage_ID { get; set; }

    [Column(Order = 1), Key, ForeignKey("Device")]
    public int Device_ID { get; set; }

    public virtual Device Device { get; set; }
    public virtual NotificationMessage NotificationMessage { get; set; }
}

public class NotificationMessage { 

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
}

        modelBuilder.Entity<Device>().HasKey(t => new { t.ID, t.ApplicationKey, t.PlatformKey, t.UDID });
```

What the problem is that whenever I want to make ID , UDID , ApplicationKey and PlatformKey define as a Composite Key with modelBuilder it gives the following error.

> NotificationMessageDevice_Device_Target_NotificationMessageDevice_Device_Source:
>   : The number of properties in the Dependent and Principal Roles in a
>   relationship constraint must be identical

I think the problem is because the navigation property on NotificationMessageDevice is not able to recognize what the primary key is on Device table. How can I resolve this problem? In addition to this I will be glad if you share your experiences improving the search performance on Entity framework. Usually the performance issue occurs on whenever I use First method without primary keys.

Comment: I'm not much for EF development, but don't you have the `ForeignKeyAttribute` on the wrong thing?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

If *Device* table has composite primary key, then you need same composite foreign key on your *NotificationMessageDevice* table. How would SQL find Device without full primary key? Also you should make these fields to be part of *NotificationMessageDevice* table primary key. Otherwise you can't guarantee primary key will be unique:

```
public class NotificationMessageDevice
{
    [Column(Order = 0), Key, ForeignKey("NotificationMessage")]
    public int NotificationMessage_ID { get; set; }

    [Column(Order = 1), Key, ForeignKey("Device")]
    public int Device_ID { get; set; }
    [Column(Order = 2), Key, ForeignKey("Device")]
    public string Device_UDID { get; set; }
    [Column(Order = 3), Key, ForeignKey("Device")]
    public string Device_ApplicationKey { get; set; }

    public virtual Device Device { get; set; }
    public virtual NotificationMessage NotificationMessage { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Is this must that we need to implement all the properties defined on composite key should be implemented at target table whenever we use Device object as a navigation property.

Comment: Yes, this will be foreign key in database. Foreign key is a primary key from parent table, so it should be exactly same. Btw if you want `PlatformKey` to be part of device PK, you need that field in NotificationMessageDevice also

Comment: Hmm one more question, is there any way to create super key on Entity Framework then ?

Comment: @kkocabiyik as far as I know, nope, no super keys

Comment: @kkocabiyik & SergeyBerezovskiy SQL PK and UNIQUE NOT NULL *declare superkeys*. The relational meaning of PK is some CK you picked for that, and a CK is a superkey containing no smaller CK. SQL allows a PK or UNIQUE NOT NULL to be declared that contains a smaller one.