# One or more validation errors were detected during model generation Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

Hi I have a problem with relationship between my tables. When i try to get values from table i have an error:

> OrderDetails_Order_Target_OrderDetails_Order_Source: : The number of
>   properties in the Dependent and Principal Roles in a relationship
>   constraint must be identical. OrderDetails_Processor_Source: :
>   Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'OrderDetails_Processor_Source' in
>   relationship 'OrderDetails_Processor'. Because the Dependent Role
>   refers to the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of
>   the Dependent Role must be '1'.
>   OrderDetails_Processor_Target_OrderDetails_Processor_Source: : The
>   number of properties in the Dependent and Principal Roles in a
>   relationship constraint must be identical.

My classes and relationship look that:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Users>().HasKey(x => x.ID_User);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Processor>().HasKey(x => x.Product_ID);
        modelBuilder.Entity<GPU>().HasKey(x => x.Product_ID);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Orders>().HasKey(x => new { x.Order_ID, x.User_ID });
        modelBuilder.Entity<OrderDetails>().HasKey(x => new { x.Order_ID, x.Product_ID });

        modelBuilder.Entity<OrderDetails>().HasRequired(x => x.Processor).WithMany(x => x.OrderDetails).HasForeignKey(x => new { x.Product_ID, x.Order_ID });
        modelBuilder.Entity<OrderDetails>().HasRequired(x => x.GPU).WithMany(x => x.OrderDetails);
        modelBuilder.Entity<OrderDetails>().HasRequired(x => x.Order).WithMany(x => x.OrderDetails);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Orders>().HasMany(x => x.OrderDetails).WithRequired(x => x.Order);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Orders>().HasRequired(x => x.User).WithMany(x => x.Orders);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Processor>().HasMany(x => x.OrderDetails).WithRequired(x => x.Processor).HasForeignKey(x => new { x.Product_ID, x.Order_ID });
        modelBuilder.Entity<GPU>().HasMany(x => x.OrderDetails).WithRequired(x => x.GPU);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Users>().HasMany(x => x.Orders).WithRequired(x => x.User);
    }

public class OrderDetails
{
    public int Order_ID { get; set; }
    public int Product_ID { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(Product_ID))]
    public Processor Processor { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(Product_ID))]
    public GPU GPU { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(Order_ID))]
    public Orders Order { get; set; }
}
public class Processor
{
    [Key]
    public int Product_ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Brand { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public ICollection<OrderDetails> OrderDetails { get; set; }
}
```

And here i get an error

```
public class EfProcessorContext : IProcessorRepository
{
    private EfDbContext context = new EfDbContext();

    public IEnumerable<Processor> Processors
    {
        get
        {
            return context.Processors.Include(x => x.OrderDetails);
        }
    }
}
```

What wrong I do?

Answer (score 0):

The reason may be for the error is incorrectly configured relations in your model.

[How to fix: The number of properties in the Dependent and Principal Roles in a relationship constraint must be identical?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11754842/how-to-fix-the-number-of-properties-in-the-dependent-and-principal-roles-in-a-r)

https://entityframework.net/knowledge-base/28699205/-the-number-of-properties-in-the-dependent-and-principal-roles-in-a-relationship-constraint-must-be-identical--issue-in-entity-framework

["The number of properties in the Dependent and Principal Roles in a relationship constraint must be identical" issue in entity framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28699205/the-number-of-properties-in-the-dependent-and-principal-roles-in-a-relationship)