# Creating entity with DateTime in primary key

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-5

Suppose we have "EfTest" database with the following table in SQL server:

```
create table Test
(
    Id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    TS DATETIME NOT NULL
    PRIMARY KEY (TS, Id)
)
```

And we want to add stuff there with EF (EF 5 in my case). We create edmx file from database in our sample project and write following code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var ctx = new EFTestEntities();

        var t = new Test();
        t.TS = DateTime.Now;

        ctx.Tests.Add(t);

        ctx.SaveChanges();
    }
```

We run it and it fails with `DbUpdateConcurrencyException` on `ctx.SaveChanges()` line, saying:

> Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected
>   number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since
>   entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries.

Obviously, no concurrency happening there. SQL Server profiler reports that following query is run by EF:

```
exec sp_executesql N'insert [dbo].[Test]([TS])
values (@0)
select [Id]
from [dbo].[Test]
where @@ROWCOUNT > 0 and [Id] = scope_identity() and [TS] = @0',N'@0 datetime2(7)',@0='2015-08-27 18:29:45.1025442'
```

Problem lies here: `@0 datetime2(7),@0='2015-08-27 18:29:45.1025442'`. `DATETIME2` is higher precision than `DATETIME` and `TS` check in the `WHERE` clause prevents it from finding the row it just inserted.

Question: putting aside the reason why I have `DATETIME` column as part of PK, how do I make EF to insert rows without throwing exceptions?

<del>I could make `TS` column to be of `DATETIME2` type, which would resolve the issue, but I don't want to waste DB space just because of some EF issue.</del> I double checked and it seems both [`DATETIME`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx) and [`DATETIME2`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335.aspx) occupy 8 bytes, so I guess I go that way.

I could edit `.edmx` file in text editor and make it think that primary key is `Id` column only (so EF wouldn't use `TS` to lookup `Id` after insert), but VS will overwrite my edits next time I update entities from DB.

Any other options?

Comment: Maybe there are better solutions but you can use Stored proc to insert into db as a last resort.

Comment: you need to specify in your model that your using a composite primary key, otherwise EF will never work see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14873169/creating-composite-key-entity-framework

Comment: I use database first approach, so EF understands very well that I have composite primary key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using `DATETIME2` as column type as there is no space trade off: both `DATETIME` and `DATETIME2` occupy 8 bytes.