# Is it possible to have two keys in the same class?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, key

I have a question. I don't really know if it's possible. I'm working on an MVC application and part of the model look like this:

```
public class EmployeeNewspaper
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Key]
    public string Appendage { get; set; }
    public string SourceInformationName { get; set; }
}
```

So my question is: Is it possible to have two keys in the same class? Or what can I do? I need to have the name and the appendage unique. Is it possible?

Comment: It's not entirely clear what the question is - is this an entity framework model or a standard MVC model? If it's a standard MVC model, do you want your unique-ness to be enforced by your code or in your user interface? (e.g. do you want a runtime error or a validation error if a duplicate is added... to something?) - if you can clarify where you want to enforce uniqueness it would be useful as the approach will differ (DB keys, hashes/equality comparer, validation rules etc)

Comment: Its an entity framework model. I want to show to the user that unique information

Comment: When I run the stored procedure in the DB I have the correct information. But when I pass the information to the model, as I only have the key in the Appendage, it it has different names, its showing me the same name in any case. So I need to make the name and the appendage key (together) both of us in any case. Did I explain myself?

Comment: You want a composite key then: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14873169/creating-composite-key-entity-framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks  [@Charle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/987509/charleh) I was actually looking for composite key and the answer is:

```
public class EmployeeNewspaper
{
    [Key][Column(Order = 0)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Key][Column(Order = 1)]
    public string Appendage { get; set; }
    public string SourceInformationName { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [**Guid**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid(v=vs.110).aspx) and get a **G**lobally **U**nique **ID**entifier.

But you will need to be aware that using this:

```
Guid MyID = new Guid();
```

will result in an all-zeros(empty) ID.

So you will need to use it this way:

```
Guid MyID = Guid.NewGuid();
```

Comment: How this does answer the question?

Comment: How can I assign the Name and the Appendage to the GUID?, thanks!

Comment: This gives you a unique ID for the instance (aside from the reference itself) but does not enforce uniqueness for any fields..

Comment: I don't really understand. There Im only creating the guid variable, but I need to assign it, right?

Comment: @SomeAnonymousPerson I think I misunderstood the question. Anyway using `Guid MyID = new Guid(Appendage);` will initialize a new instance of the Guid structure by using the value represented by the specified string. Hope this helps