# Identity framework composite key

Tags: entity-framework, key, asp.net-identity, composite

I'm working with Entity Framework and identity framework (`IdentityUser`, `IdentityRole`). I have a table with a composite key (table `Country`) that points to the `Users` table.

Unfortunately, EF can only build a relation when all keys are the same, otherwise you'll get this:

> The number of properties in the Dependent and Principal Roles in a relationship constraint must be identical.

So, how can I handle this? Right now I have tried to add this composite key to the `ApplicationUser:IdentityUser` too, but in this way I have to add the composite key to all entities of the identity framework (that means user, role, claim, login, ...).

Here are my model classes:

```
class Country
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    [Column(Order = 2)]
    public int Version { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [ForeignKey(nameof(Chief))]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public string Chief_Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [ForeignKey(nameof(Chief)), Column(Order = 2)]
    public int Chief_Version { get; set; }

    public virtual ApplicationUser Chief{ get; set; }
}

class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public override string Id
    {
        get { return base.Id; }
        set { base.Id = value; }
    }

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    [Column(Order = 2)]

    public int Version { get; set; }
}
```

Nico

Comment: right now you have a two keys on applicationuser, and two one-column FK's from Country to ApplicationUser. I'm not sure how to do this in data annotation, in fluent API it is modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().HasKey(x=>new{x.Id, x.Version}); and modelBuilder.Entity<Country>().HasRequired(x=>x.Chief).WithMany().HasForeignKey(x=>new{x.Chief_Id, x.Chief_Version});

Answer (score 0):

Look into your foreign key `nameof(Chief)`, you might not have the full relationship set up.

There is another question that might help [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14873169/creating-composite-key-entity-framework)