# ASP.NET MVC Code First Migration - Model with 2 Primary Keys

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-migrations

I want to create a table that is similar to the `AspNetUserRoles` table in my database that has these columns:

```
User_id
Role_id
```

These columns are related to the user and role tables

How can I create one using my model? I have tried it like this:

```
public class AspNetUserRolesExtendedDetails
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    public ApplicationUser UserId { get; set; }
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public AspNetRolesExtendedDetails RoleId { get; set; }
}
```

But when I try to run migrations, this error appears:

> AspNetUserRolesExtendedDetails: : EntityType 'AspNetUserRolesExtendedDetails' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
>   AspNetUserRolesExtendedDetails: EntityType: EntitySet 'AspNetUserRolesExtendedDetails' is based on type 'AspNetUserRolesExtendedDetails' that has no keys defined.

How can I create a table like this and what is the proper name for it?

EDIT:

When I update my model like this:

```
public class AspNetUserRolesExtendedDetails
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    [ForeignKey("AspNetUsers")]
    public ApplicationUser UserId { get; set; }
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [ForeignKey("AspNetRolesExtendedDetails")]
    public AspNetRolesExtendedDetails RoleId { get; set; }
}
```

I get this error:

> The ForeignKeyAttribute on property 'RoleId' on type 'App.Models.AspNetUserRolesExtendedDetails' is not valid. The foreign key name 'AspNetRolesExtendedDetails' was not found on the dependent type 'App.Models.AspNetUserRolesExtendedDetails'. The Name value should be a comma separated list of foreign key property names.

Update:

```
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    [ForeignKey("Id")]
    public String UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [ForeignKey("Id")]
    public String RoleId { get; set; }
    public virtual AspNetRolesExtendedDetails AspNetRolesExtendedDetails { get; set; }
```

This is what I have now but I'm getting this error:

> The ForeignKeyAttribute on property 'UserId' on type 'App.AspNetUserRolesExtendedDetails' is not valid. The navigation property 'Id' was not found on the dependent type 'App.Models.AspNetUserRolesExtendedDetails'. The Name value should be a valid navigation property name.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14873169/creating-composite-key-entity-framework

Comment: I'm using Strings as Ids

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to find a solution. For some reason copying the Objects name directly worked for me.

```
public class AspNetUserRolesExtendedDetails
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    [ForeignKey("ApplicationUser")]
    public String UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [ForeignKey("AspNetRolesExtendedDetails")]
    public String RoleId { get; set; }
    public virtual AspNetRolesExtendedDetails AspNetRolesExtendedDetails { get; set; }
}
```